# ASP.NET - The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp, web-config

I am trying to deploy a website on a server, I tried making a blank website but I keep getting this error.
I looked it up and found many solutions involving the web.config, none of them worked for me.

This is my web.config after making some changes I found on here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
    <location>
        <system.webServer>
            <defaultDocument enabled="true">
                <files>
                    <add value="home.aspx"/>
                </files>
            </defaultDocument>
            <directoryBrowse enabled="false"/>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

I have never published an ASP.NET website to a server, I used FTP to publish it and that seems to work all files are on the server.

I tried adding `<location>`

I tried adding

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
       <files>
          <add value="insertion.aspx" />
       </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

and

```
<system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

Here are some pictures taken from the website's dashboard

[Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoTNr.png)

[App Pool settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ojnM.png)

[index pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElMlA.png)

[Folder settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Rw8V.png)

Comment: Often depends on hosting company, and what features and setup/support tools they have. Often you are free to publish a working web site application to the root of the hosting service. However, you might want to publish to a sub folder. But, if you do that, then how does the web hosting know that some folder supposed to be a web site as opposed to the existing root folder of that site? Thus many providers will have setup area/tools to "turn on" or "tell" the server that the ONE folder is to be a WHOLE web site application. So hosting setup tools allow to you "turn on" a folder as a whole site.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal , I had contact with the hosting company and they tried to help me, but they didn't know either. I have to put the website into a /www folder. I can also select a default index page on their dashboard.
But it still doesn't work and I don't know what I have to add into the web.config to maje it work

Comment: If you publish to the root, then you overwriting everything on that existing site.  If they have a option to "set and create a folder" as application, then that is the option you should use/try. In most cases, the root by default (I would assume) is already defined as a web site application, but that may well not be the case. So, in the IIS configuration screen (which will be limited feature wise compare to full GUI version on a typical server), you thus want to see/find/check/look for the option that "turns on" that folder as a web site application (assuming that's your vs project type)

Comment: It is somewhat doubtful that the web config is the issue - it might be, but without seeing the hosting setup with our own eyes, it rather difficult to make judgement calls here without seeing what you are seeing. We assume windows hosting, and not Linux, and we assume IIS support for the web server (assuming this is a asp.net webforms site). You not even noted here what kind of vs project this is, and there is a boatload of vs types of projects - each one can be VAST different in how you publish such sites). So, do you have a asp.net web site, or a asp.net web site application? (details matter

Comment: You might not deploy your project correctly, I believe that you can read this blog post https://windowswebhostingreview.com/asp-net-5-fully-released-how-to-publish-asp-net-5-in-shared-hosting/.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I have an ASP.NET Web Application (.NET FrameWork), I don't have access to many settings, I added the default page on the hosting site and I have now added /www as a web application folder but this didn't change anything.
The /www folder was already created by the hosting company so I asume it was already setup, the hosting is on Windows, I will try to edit the post and add some pictures from the hosting companys site